# How to control the user prompt in a Facebook Feed dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ui

Is there a way to control the user prompt (defaults to "Say something about this...") in a facebook [feed dialog using the Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)?

I don't want to prefill the content for the user, I just want to give them a bit better direction ("Let your friends know lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...").

It appears that there is a property `user_message_prompt` but it doesn't seem to work. I assume it's been deprecated.

Sorry to post such a general question here - I find FB's API documentation to not always be helpful (no offense to FB folks on here, who are super helpful!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this is **not possible**. Why not communicate your message before initiating the dialog along with the call to action button?

Comment: When you say this is not possible do you mean `user_message_prompt` is deprecated?

Comment: Thanks. Communicating instructions before spawning the window is suboptimal for UI (users tend not to read instructions to begin with, and have a hard time retaining messages from one screen to the next) but may be my best bet.